# getView is called several times for the first position in GridView

Tags: android

I have an adapter with this getView:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("getView gv", position+"");

    NewsLine holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_entry, parent, false);
        holder = new NewsLine();

        holder.iv= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (NewsLine) convertView.getTag();
    }

    NewsItem item=news.ITEMS.get(position);
    //---------

    if(item.imgurl!=null && item.imgurl.compareToIgnoreCase("null")!=0) 
    {
        holder.iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
        mMemoryCache.loadBitmap(item.imgurl, holder.iv,position);
    }
    else
        holder.iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    //-------------




    return convertView;
}
```

I have two problems:

1. the getView is called several times for position 0 (the bitmap is downloaded with an AsyncTask if its missed in a LruCache). I have an animation (alpha from 0-1) that restarts several times for that position.
2. because I'm recycling the view sometimes you can see the old imageView content for a fraction of a second.

//----

And here is the cache class (only heap):

```
public class SetImgAT extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> {
private static SetImgAT instance;   
private Animation FadeInAnimation;

private SetImgAT(int size, Context context) {
    super(size);
    FadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fadein);
}

public static synchronized SetImgAT getInstance(int size, Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new SetImgAT(size, context);
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return (value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight());
}

public void loadBitmap(String url, ImageView imageView,int pos) {
    Bitmap bitmap = instance.get(url.hashCode() + "");
    if (bitmap != null) {
        Log.d("ImageCache", "hit - "+url.hashCode()+"pos:"+pos);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        imageView.invalidate();
    } else {
        Log.d("ImageCache", "miss");
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        task.execute(url);
    }
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView mImageView;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        mImageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
        Bitmap Picture = null;


        if (url[0] != null && url[0].compareToIgnoreCase("null") != 0) {
            Log.d("GetBMP from", url[0]);

            URL img_value = null;
            try {
                img_value = new URL(url[0]);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (Picture == null) {
                Log.d("deb", "no bitmap");
            } else {
                Log.d("got deb", "got bitmap to "+url[0].hashCode());                   
                instance.put(url[0].hashCode()+"", Picture);
            }

        }
        return Picture;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            Log.d("deb", "set bitmap");
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            //mImageView.startAnimation(FadeInAnimation);
        }

    }
}
```

//----------------

}

Thank you! :)

Comment: For question #2, try calling `mMemoryCache.loadBitmap()` before `setVisibility()` to prevent the old image from appearing.

Comment: "the getView is called several times for position 0" -- This is perfectly normal behavior. There are no rules as to how many times `getView()` will be called for a position. Overall, StackOverflow is for programming questions, and you have not asked a question.

Comment: Sam it didn't work, it seems there is allot more to take care of, I'm going trough the sample for caching bitmaps from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html . at CommonsWare thank you, I don't think I need to rephrase this as a question, maybe you can try.

Comment: I am also having problems with this. It seems position 0 is called 2 times every time a new row appears in my gridview. Very strange

Comment: @CommonsWare Is this considered "normal" for it fire multiple times?

Comment: @KarlMorrison: As you can tell by reading my comment on this question, yes, it is normal.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for clarifying it, I didn't know if you were directly answering to how the user implemented it or if it was more a general answer!

Comment: @KarlMorrison: Particularly with `ListView`, `GridView`, and other constant-display `AdapterView` classes (e.g., perhaps not `Spinner` or `AutoCompleteTextView`), the number of times `getView()` is called will vary. AFAIK, it'll depend a bit on Android version (taking into account framework optimizations over time) and what container classes are involved (parent of the `AdapterView` and contents of the `AdapterView`). I'll need to run some tests to see if `RecyclerView` avoids this...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar behavior when scrolling back and forth or haphazardly calling notifyDataSetChanged().

As an enhancement to what you are doing now I would suggest using Picasso instead since it handles this case very well, in addition to the fade in animation.

A one liner in your getView():

```
Picasso.with(context).load(urlToLoad).into(imageView);
```

See:
http://square.github.io/picasso/